# PHP inheretance working on 1 instance not on another

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a CRUD object and I have two objects, admin and post, that extend the CRUD object. I'm going to be validating on the front end as well as the back end when I am through, but currently I'm working on the back end validations. The CRUD object has global create, update, and validate methods. The Post object overrides the validation method fine and works. The admin overrides the validate method and doesn't seem to call the parent or the child.

Example below:

```
<?php 
class CRUD {

  protected function validate(){
   $this->errors =[]
   //no error checking here, but when I put any error checking here it doesnt
   //fire on admin either.
  return $this->errors;
 }

  public function create(){
    $this->validate();
    if(!empty($this->errors){return false}
    //query which works on all classes.
  }

}

class Admin extends CRUD{
  protected function validate(){
    $this->errors = [];
    //a bunch of error checking functions that work for post class
    return $this->errors;
  }

  public function create(){
    $this->hashpassword(); //just sets $this->password to a hash
    return parent::create();
  }

}

class Post extends CRUD {
  protected function validate() {
    $this->errors =[];
    //a bunch of functioning validations
    return $this->errors;
  }

}

?>
```

Whether I just run the function as is, I comment out the `override create()` function and use the inherited version that doesn't hash the password, or I try to put the validation functions in the parent class nothing is filling `$this->errors` for admin. It works totally fine for the post class. My question is, why wont the validation method work on the Admin class?

**Edit Copy and Pasting the actual classes **
The CRUD class:

```
<?php

class DatabaseObject {

  static protected $db;
  static protected $table_name;
  static protected $db_columns = [];
  public $errors = [];


  public static function set_db($db){
    self::$db = $db;
  }

  static public function find_by_sql($sql){
   $result =  self::$db->query($sql);
   if(!$result) {
     exit("Database Query Failed");
   }
      //convert results into objects
    $object_array=[];
      while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $object_array[] = static::instantiate($record);
    }
      $result->free();
      return $object_array;
    }

  static public function find_all(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name;
    return static::find_by_sql($sql);
  }

  static public function find_by_id($id){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name;
      $sql .= " WHERE id='" . self::$db->escape_string($id) . "'";
      $object_array = static::find_by_sql($sql);
      if(!$object_array){
        return false;
      }
      return array_shift($object_array);
    }

  static protected function instantiate($record){
    $object = new static;
    //could assign things by hand but its faster and easier to do it dunamically
    //plus it's reusable.
    foreach($record as $property => $value){
      if(property_exists($object, $property)){
        $object->$property = $value;
      }
    }
    return $object;
  }

  protected function validate() {
    $this->errors = [];
      $this->errors[] = "bar";
    return $this->errors;
  }

  protected function create(){
      $this->validate();
      if(!empty($errors))
      {return false;}

      $attributes = $this->sanitize_attributes();

      $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name . " (";
      $sql .= join(',', array_keys($attributes));
      $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
      $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
      $sql .= "')";
      $result = self::$db->query($sql);
      if ($result){
        $this->id = static::$db->insert_id;
      }
      return $result;
    }

       //attributes are the properties which have the db columns excluding id

  protected function update(){
    $this->validate();
    if(!empty($errors)){return false;}

    $attributes = $this->sanitize_attributes();
    $attribute_pairs = [];
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
      $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE " . self::$db->escape_string(static::$table_name) . " SET ";
    $sql .= join(', ', $attribute_pairs);
    $sql .= " WHERE id='" . self::$db->escape_string($this->id) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = self::$db->query($sql);
    return $result;
  }

  public function save(){
    if(isset($this->id)){
      return $this->update();
    } else {
      return $this->create();
    }
  }

  public function merge_attributes($args){
    foreach($args as $key => $value) {
      if(property_exists($this, $key) && !is_null($value)){
        $this->$key = $value;
      }
    }
  }

  public function attributes() {
      $attributes = [];

      foreach(static::$db_columns as $column) {
        if($column == 'id'){ continue; }
        $attributes[$column] = $this->$column;

      }
      return $attributes;
  }

   protected function sanitize_attributes() {
      $attributes = $this->attributes();
      $sanitized =[];
      foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
        $sanitized[$key] = self::$db->escape_string($value);
      }
      return $sanitized;
    }

  public function delete(){
      $sql = "DELETE FROM " . self::$db->escape_string(static::$table_name) . " ";
      $sql .= "WHERE id='";
      $sql .= self::$db->escape_string($this->id);
      $sql .= "' LIMIT 1";

      $result = self::$db->query($sql);
      return $result;
      //after deleting the instance is still around
      //which is useful so you can say $this->poop was deleted
      //but we cant call CRUD functions
  }



}
?>
```

The Admin Class:

```
<?php

class Admin extends DatabaseObject {
  static protected $table_name = 'admins';
  static protected $db_columns = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'hashed_password'];

  public $id;
  public $first_name;
  public $last_name;
  public $email;
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $confirm_password;
  protected $hashed_password;
  protected $password_required = true;


 public function __construct($args = []){
   $this->first_name = $args['first_name'] ?? '';
   $this->last_name = $args['last_name'] ?? '';
   $this->email = $args['email'] ?? '';
   $this->username = $args['username'] ?? '';
   $this->password = $args['password'] ?? '';
   $this->confirm_password = $args['confirm_password'] ?? '';
 }

  public function label() {
    return $this->username . " Name: " . $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
  }


  private function hash_password(){
      $this->hashed_password = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  }

  protected function validate() {
    $this->errors = parent::validate();
    $this->errors[] = "foo";
    if(is_blank($this->first_name)) {
      $this->errors[] = "First name cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($this->first_name, array('min' => 2, 'max' => 255))) {
      $this->errors[] = "First name must be between 2 and 255 characters.";
    }

    if(is_blank($this->last_name)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Last name cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($this->last_name, array('min' => 2, 'max' => 255))) {
      $this->errors[] = "Last name must be between 2 and 255 characters.";
    }

    if(is_blank($this->email)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Email cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($this->email, array('max' => 255))) {
      $this->errors[] = "Last name must be less than 255 characters.";
    } elseif (!has_valid_email_format($this->email)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Email must be a valid format.";
    }

    if(is_blank($this->username)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Username cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($this->username, array('min' => 8, 'max' => 255))) {
      $this->errors[] = "Username must be between 8 and 255 characters.";
    }

    if(is_blank($this->password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password cannot be blank.";
    } elseif (!has_length($this->password, array('min' => 12))) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password must contain 12 or more characters";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $this->password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $this->password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $this->password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password must contain at least 1 number";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/', $this->password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password must contain at least 1 symbol";
    }

    if(is_blank($this->confirm_password)) {
      $this->errors[] = "Confirm password cannot be blank.";
    } elseif ($this->password !== $this->confirm_password) {
      $this->errors[] = "Password and confirm password must match.";
    }

    return $this->errors;
  }

  protected function create() {

    $this->hash_password();

    $result = parent::create();
    return $result;

  }

  protected function update(){
    if($this->password != ''){
      $this->hash_password();
    } else {
      $this->password_required = false;
    }
    $result = parent::update();
    return $result;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you know about __indentation__?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited to include some indentation and I forgot to type that I extended CRUD.

Comment: `protected function validate()` returns __nothing__ in `Admin`.

Comment: I'm so sorry again. I typed this out instead of copy pasting and I was moving so fast I forgot to put the return.

Comment: Please, check your code __twice__ and provide the code how you check that nothing is returned. People are here 24/7.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry. I've just been frantic and confused. I didn't want to copy and paste all my code because a lot of it isn't pertinent. I should have been more careful. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can set $this->errors, you need to add **errors** as a property in either the CRUD or Admin class.

Comment: Failing to do so will just create a public property.

Comment: Wouldn't the public property be exactly what I want? I added public $errors = []; to the CRUD and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parents `validate` method to be called, you should include `parent::validate();` in your code. Judging from the code you provided, your Admin class would look something like this:

```
class Admin extends CRUD{
  protected function validate(){
    $this->errors = parent::validate();
    //a bunch of error checking functions that work for post class
    return $this->errors;
  }

  public function create(){
    $this->hashpassword(); //just sets $this->password to a hash
    return parent::create();
  }

}
```

The reason you would assign the result of `parent::validate()` to `$this->errors` is because the validate method resets the `$this->errors` array, thus removing all the errors.

Comment: the parent create() calls $this->validate(); do you need to call the parent every time you override a child?

Comment: Wouldn't I want the error checking on Admin to start out blank so only admin errors are reported?

Comment: Yes, you have to do this every time if you want to call the parent from a overridden method. This is how inheritance works, it overrides a method so you can (potentially) change functionality without calling the parents method.

Comment: Yes, you can start it out blank. However in your code, when you call the parents implementation of `validate`, it will reset the `errors` array again, thereby removing the errors you set before. When you call it like this, you prevent that from happening.

Comment: I added this to the validate function and it still passes over my validations.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I run create() on Admin whether it's the create inherited or the override I wrote, it passes over all validations from the parent and the child. When I run create() from post it works perfectly.

Comment: I need more context to be able to give you an answer to that. Maybe something's wrong in the validation itself? What happens when you deliberately add an error, does it still pass?

Comment: I deliberately added $this->errors[] = "foo"; to the parent validate and $this->errors[] = "bar" to the admin validate and neither came through nor did they stop the record from being added to the database.

Comment: Also, I added a div to the show page and added some text to make sure it wasn't a caching issue. And I added the parent validate to the post and the foo is coming through as an error and stops the record from being added to the database.

Comment: I need to see more of the code to be able to provide an answer to your problem

Comment: Can I copy and paste the admin and the crud object here or is that too much?

Comment: I'm signing up for an account now. I've also pasted the CRUD and Admin classes in my original post.